# Calling a method of a class within another class?

Tags: c++, class, syntax, methods, linked-list

I have defined the following class for a node in a linked list:

```
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
    T value;
    List<T> wordList; // <--------
    ListItem<T> *next;
    ListItem<T> *prev;

    ListItem(T theVal)
    {
       this->value = theVal;
       this->next = NULL;
       this->prev = NULL;
    }
};
```

The above class contains another class, i.e List, which has its own functions, one of which is insertAtEnd. I have created a ListItem and I want to change the value of its wordList component by calling insertAtEnd. What is the syntax for doing that?

Here's the list class:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
    ListItem<T> *head;

public:

    // Constructor
    List();         //done

    //test function
    void displaylist();

    // Copy Constructor
    List(const List<T>& otherList);       //done

    // Destructor
    ~List();

    // Insertion Functions
    void insertAtHead(T item);        //done
    void insertAtTail(T item);        //done
    void insertAfter(T toInsert, T afterWhat);    //done
    void insertSorted(T item);                    //done

    // Lookup Functions
    ListItem<T> *getHead();                       //done
    ListItem<T> *getTail();                       //done
    ListItem<T> *searchFor(T item);               //done

    // Deletion Functions
    void deleteElement(T item);                   //done
    void deleteHead();
    void deleteTail();                            //done

    // Utility Functions
    int length();                                 //done
 };
```

Here's the implementation for the insertAtTail function.

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::insertAtTail(T item)
{
    ListItem<T>* a = new ListItem<T>(item);

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=a;
    }

    else
    {
        ListItem<T>* temp;
        temp=head;

        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next=a;
        a->prev=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I have created a ListItem and I want to change the value of its wordList component by calling insertAtEnd."* Perhaps show what you have for that so far. All you have here is a decl and a constructor (and a missing initializer list where a copy-ctor for your member should be invoked).

Comment: You should look for some tutorials about C++. I am not even sure if this is valid C++... Try [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) first.

Comment: `YourListItemVarName.wordList.insertAtEnd(..params...)`

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
wordList.insertAtEnd( .... arguments ....);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know your exact use case, but I **really doubt** a `ListItem` should have a `List`
2. To use `wordList` simply do `this->wordList.insertAtEnd(........)` (`this` is not obligatory here).

Comment: What I'm trying to create is function that takes in a file containing several hundred words, make a two-dimensional linked list with each node containing another list that contains all the words starting with a particular alphabet.
The function I'm trying to make is declared like this:
List<string> Dictionary()
I'd been instructed to add a List<T> wordList object in the ListItem struct to proceed with this task.